# My app crashes and creates an SQLite compiling error when clicking an item in ListView. What is wrong?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

Here is the crash report in logcat:

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Press": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT ID FROM BUTTONMANAGER WHERE FULL_NAME = James Smith AND DATE_ADDED = 7/30/2020
```

I am trying to get the Item ID of a row in the database where the name of the item in the listview matches FULL_NAME and the date added matches DATE_ADDED.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I looked over the syntax of my queryString and didn't find any errors. The app does not crash when I only check for FULL_NAME and not DATE_ADDED. However, I want to check for DATE_ADDED to ensure that I am deleting the correct row in the database.

This is my DatabaseHelper code:

```
    public Cursor getItemID(String name, String dateAdded) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String queryString = "SELECT " + COLUMN_ID + " FROM " + BUTTON_MANAGER + " WHERE " + COLUMN_FULL_NAME + " = " + name + " AND " + COLUMN_DATE_ADDED + " = " + dateAdded;

    Cursor data = db.rawQuery(queryString, null);
    return data;
}
```

This is my mainActivity:

```
        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);
    mainListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String name = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            String dateAdded = dateButton.getText().toString();

            Cursor data = databaseHelper.getItemID(name, dateAdded); //Get ID associated with name of item in ListView
            int itemID = -1;
            while(data.moveToNext()) {
                itemID = data.getInt(0);
            }

            if (itemID > -1) {
                Intent editExerciseIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, edit_existing_exercise.class);
                editUserIntent.putExtra("id", itemID);
                editUserIntent.putExtra("name", name);
                editUserIntent.putExtra("dateAdded", dateAdded);
                startActivity(editUserIntent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The crash happens when I click the item in the ListView.

More of the crash report:

```
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Press": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT ID FROM BUTTONMANAGER WHERE FULL_NAME = James Smith AND DATE_ADDED = '7/30/2020'
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1016)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:623)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1545)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1484)
    at com.mycompany.mainapp.DatabaseHelper.getItemID(DatabaseHelper.java:118)
    at com.mycompany.mainapp.MainActivity$15.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:404)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:330)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1187)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3179)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4097)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
```

Comment: Don’t you need quotes around string values in sql?

Comment: I added quotes around the string variables in the queryString, but I get the same logcat error when I click on the item in the ListView.

Comment: Is there any more to the error or any more SQL queries?  It's kind of odd that it says there's an error near "Press", but that string doesn't appear anywhere.

Comment: You should learn about prepared statements.

Comment: I have a couple other queryStrings that create this table and other tables and allow me to create, edit, and delete data in those tables. I thought it was odd as well that it mentions "Press", but I have no place where I wrote Press. I will update my original post with more of the error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the syntax error is due to your slashes in date added.

Try this

```
String queryString = "SELECT " + COLUMN_ID + " FROM " + BUTTON_MANAGER + " WHERE " + COLUMN_FULL_NAME + " = " + name + " AND " + COLUMN_DATE_ADDED + " = '" + dateAdded + "'";
```

Comment: I changed the queryString to your suggestion but got the same error when I clicked on an item in the ListView.

Comment: The logcat error says to look specifically at Cursor data = databaseHelper.getItemID(name, dateAdded); //Get ID associated with name of item in ListView

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this question has a solution. I had to add extra quotations around the variables in the queryString. The syntax for the queryString looks like this:

```
String queryString = "SELECT " + COLUMN_ID + " FROM " + BUTTON_MANAGER + " WHERE " + COLUMN_FULL_NAME + " = '" + name + "'" + " AND " + COLUMN_DATE_ADDED + " = '" + dateAdded + "'";
```

@Dave Newton your response was correct, I didn't use the syntax correctly when I originally responded.

Thank you to everyone who responded and helped me out. I appreciate it.